# Farm Solution. List Instance and List Definition in different Solutions. Differences in schema.xml

Tags: 2013, feature, farm-solution

I have two farm solutions.

One is an old version, where I created some lists. So in the Solution (Visual Studio) I find my List Definitions, as well as List Incances.

```
Listname
    -ListnameInstance
         -Elements.xml (from instance)
    -Elements.xml (from definition)
    -Schema.xml (from definition)
```

When we deployed this solution on the test environment, we changed some stuff on the lists. Not only custom forms, but also deleted/added new columns, and changed existing ones (datatype)

What we did now, is, we created a new Template from the Sitecollection of the Dev Environment and created a new Farm Solution based on this template.

In this new solution, there are no List Definitions, only List Instances. And they point to a Feature, where they should find the List Definition. This Feature is from the first Farm Solution.

The problem is, there are a lot of changes / differences in the Schema.xml from the original Definition, and from the new one, that is found in the List Instance in the template solution.

```
ListnameInstance
    -Elements.xml
    -Schema.xml
```

So I thought of 2 ways to get this work.

First one:

I deploy the original solution with the old, not changed, List definitions, and then deploy the new solution. This will only work if SharePoint realizes there ae differences and uses the new schema.xml. **Does this happen?** I have no idea if this works. Does anyone have experience on this?

Second one:

If first one is not possible, I thought of using the Schema.xml from the new solution and replace the Schema.xml from the old solution and then go for the First way. Here the same question. **Is this possible?**

Hopefully someone came to the same issue in the past and can help me.
Thank you